# Updating excel spreadsheet with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm keeping track of a rather large inventory database of various instruments. I need a good way to update said inventory system. The system is made up of many spreadsheets, one for each instrument, essentially. The main methods of organization I've been using is the instrument and the part number. As of right now, I have a script that--using the pandas package--will reference a master file in two categories with the spreadsheet: part number and instrument, and will update the master by removing duplicates. So for instance, if I have four 5 ohm resistors, and that number gets updated to seven 5 ohm resistors, I run the program and it updates the master with the new value of seven.

What I need it to do now is to remove omissions entirely. In other words, I go from four 5 ohm resistors to zero 5 ohm resistors, which is to say, there is no entry at all. I need a way for the program to edit the master file and remove that entry entirely. I'd also like a way to be able to reference the master with x number of files that the user inputs as opposed to just one at a time. But I'm not so certain I'm versed enough in python or pandas to make this happen, hence the question on stack overflow!

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated! Here is the program so far:

```
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os, sys
from os.path import basename

# CSV IMPORT DEFINED FUNCTION
def csvImport(ftype, fpath):
    try:
       if ftype == 1:
           masterdata = pd.read_csv(fpath)
           return masterdata

       if ftype == 2:
           updateddata = pd.read_csv(fpath)
           updateddata['originfile'] = pd.Series(os.path.basename(fpath), \
                                                 index=updateddata.index)             
           return updateddata

    except Exception as e:
       print "\nUnable to import CSV file. Error {}".format(e)
       sys.exit(1)

# EXCEL IMPORT DEFINED FUNCTION
def xlImport(ftype, fpath):
    try:
        if ftype == 1:
           masterdata = pd.read_excel(fpath, 0)
           return masterdata

        if ftype == 2:
           updateddata = pd.read_excel(fpath, 0)
           updateddata['orginfile'] = pd.Series(os.path.basename(fpath), \
                                                index=updateddata.index)             
           return updateddata

    except Exception as e:
       print "\nUnable to import Excel file. Error {}".format(e)
       sys.exit(1)

# MASTER FILE USER INPUT DEFINED FUNCTION
def masterfile():
    while True:
       masterfile = raw_input("Enter the path to the master file: ")    
       if masterfile.endswith(".csv"):
          return csvImport(1, masterfile)
          break
       elif masterfile.endswith(".xlsx"):
          return xlImport(1, masterfile)          
          break
       else:
          print "\nPlease enter a proper CSV format file."

# UPDATED FILE USER INPUT DEFINED FUNCTION
def updatefile():
    while True:       
       updatedfile = raw_input("\nEnter the path to the updated file: ")
       if updatedfile.endswith(".csv"):
          return csvImport(2, updatedfile)
          break
       elif updatedfile.endswith(".xlsx"):
          return xlImport(2, updatedfile)
          break
       else:
          print "\nPlease enter a proper Excel file in xlsx format."

# CALLING OPENING FUNCTIONS
masterdata = masterfile()
updateddata = updatefile()

# CONCATENATING DATA FRAMES
combineddata = pd.concat([updateddata, masterdata])

# REMOVING DUPLICATES
finaldata = combineddata.drop_duplicates(['Item'])

# SETTING FINAL PATH BY USER INPUT
while True:       
    final = raw_input("\nWhere do you want the file, and what do you want to name it? \
                      (e.g., C:\path_to_file\name_of_file.xlsx): ")
    if final.endswith(".xlsx"):
        break
    else:
        print "\nPlease enter a proper Excel file in xlsx format."

# OUTPUTTING DATA FRAME TO FILE 
finaldata.to_excel(final)
print "\nSuccessfully outputted appended data frame to Excel!"

# OPENING OUTPUTTED FILE
# (NOTE: PYTHON STILL RUNS UNTIL SPREADSHEET IS CLOSED)
subprocess.call(final, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea for your first question -- this acts likes a sql `select` statement:

```
nozeros_finaldata = finaldata[finaldata['ColumnName'] != 0]
```

replace `'ColumnName'` with the name of your column that went from four to zero; it will return a new dataframe.  Then use `nozeros_finaldata.to_excel(final)`

For your second question:  You could use a while loop and ask the user if they have more files.

```
# CALLING OPENING FUNCTIONS
more_files = True
while more_files:
    masterdata = masterfile()
    updateddata = updatefile()

    # CONCATENATING DATA FRAMES
    combineddata = pd.concat([updateddata, masterdata])

    # REMOVING DUPLICATES
    finaldata = combineddata.drop_duplicates(['Item'])
    finaldata.dropna(subset=['originfile'],inplace=True)

    # SETTING FINAL PATH BY USER INPUT
    while True:       
        final = raw_input("\nWhere do you want the file, and what do you want to name it? \
                      (e.g., C:\path_to_file\name_of_file.xlsx): ")
        if final.endswith(".xlsx"):
            break
        else:
            print "\nPlease enter a proper Excel file in xlsx format."

    # OUTPUTTING DATA FRAME TO FILE 
    finaldata.to_excel(final)
    print "\nSuccessfully outputted appended data frame to Excel!"

    # OPENING OUTPUTTED FILE
    # (NOTE: PYTHON STILL RUNS UNTIL SPREADSHEET IS CLOSED)
    subprocess.call(final, shell=True)

    user_run_again = raw_input("\nWould you like to run another file?" )
    if user_run_again == "Yes":
        more_files = True
    else:
        more_files = False
```

You may want to do some exception handling for the last raw_input, just trying to provide some ideas.

Comment: This looks good. I just need to convince one of the engineers to actually place a zero rather than omit.

Any ideas on a method to find missing entries and remove those, as opposed to searching for a zero? One thought might be to use a Linux-esque 'diff' script, then remove whatever it finds, but I'm not sure how/if there's a good way to implement that here.

Comment: I see, sorry, I misunderstood that a zero entry actually means no entry at all.  So you want to remove the 5 ohm entry from the master file if there is no 5 ohm entry in the update file?

Comment: Precisely. You method would work, but it might inconvenience those working on the design. The entry would be omitted entirely, and I need that change to be reflected in the master after combining the latest excel file.

Comment: I could be missing something, why not just save the updated csv as the new master?  I did run the program and it seems like you just want to keep only the entries in the `updateddata`. Might need a simple example workflow, with the headers and a couple sample rows.

Comment: It's an issue of, there are many different csv files that are updated constantly by multiple parties. If one person forgets to put a zero in, then the program, at present, doesn't remove the old entry. It will update values if they change, but if someone deletes the entry it will remain in the masterfile, and some of these components can cost hundreds or thousands of dollars.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer, you should use [dropna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), which will remove records with no entry in your `['originfile']` column.